# Create a turf polygon from extents to check intersection with other polygons

Tags: coordinates, openlayers-2, turf

I am storing the bbox of layers as strings, 
as the following string :

```
var layerExtent='[768039.2602094524, 5772524.37609651, 2313901.7202488566, 7435794.111581946]'
```

and I'm using this method to create a polygon from this bbox(extent) :

```
var bboxPolygon = turf.bboxPolygon(layerExtent);
```

but the polygon created has a weird coordinates so I can't use it to check intersection with other polygon with turf using:

```
var intersection = turf.intersect(bboxPolygon , item);
```

The structure of this polygon is as following:
[image]

so no intersection is detected, can you please give me ideas how make this work ?
can I create a proper polygon from extents so I could use it to check for intersection with other polygons ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please include any code or error messages as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason was that the turf.bboxPolygon takes a list of floats/numbers and not a string